# Best S&P 500 index tracker available in EU countries?

Tags: index-fund, standard-and-poors-500, europe

When I was living in the US I've started investing into the Vanguard 500 Index Fund. However, now I'm back in Europe and are looking for similar index funds that are tracking S&P 500.

Does anyone know what the best trackers are? Are there any significant differences between them or can I just choose any?

I found for example this one: [db x-trackers S&P 500 Euro Hedged Index UCITS ETF](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XSPE%3aIM)

Comment: I'm not sure specific fund recommendations are on-topic here, per the [FAQ](http://money.stackexchange.com/faq), but furthermore, what do you mean by "best"? Lowest expense ratio, lowest share price/NAV, etc.? [iShares](http://de.ishares.com/en/rc/funds/IBCF:DB) offers one such fund with an expense ratio of 0.45%, while [RBS](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etfs/rbs+market+access+s+p+500+eur+hedged+index+etf+LU0562681899) offers one with an ER of 0.30%. Both claim to track the S&P500 Euro Hedged Index, but hedging differences may contribute to the different expense ratios.

Comment: So I guess the difference in the expense ration e.g. compared to [VOO](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0968&FundIntExt=INT) (only 0.05%) comes from the hedging against the EUR?

Comment: That's definitely part of it. Vanguard also has lower expense ratios than many other fund companies, even when currency hedging isn't involved (take Fidelity's [S&P 500 index fund](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/315911206); it's ER is 0.10%). Since currency hedging may rely on OTC instruments, I don't know the details of the funds' respective hedging strategies. I answered your [other question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/22537/7590) with some details on hedging, but that's about as specific as my knowledge of what these funds are doing gets.

Answer (score 3):

Vanguard now has a S&P 500 tracking ETF based in Ireland that may meet your needs.

Comment: https://www.vanguard.co.uk/uk/portal/investments/etf